# CodeIgniter Persistent URL attach with every URL

Tags: codeigniter

In CI, I want to attach selected filter (in `$_GET` method) 
to appear for every link I click.
This filter are persistent so is this filters selected in any page should be available for any other page in project.

For example, I selected dealerID, GroupId in one page, let's say dealer in page **www.domain.com/dealers?dealerId=2&groupId=10** page, then if I click this another link named **www.domain.com/group**s the groups page should look like `www.domain.com/groups?dealerId=2&groupId=10` that was selected in previous page.

And one more thing: I am using a main controller that will be inherited by all controllers for some reason.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could have one universal $data['filter'] variable that is going to preserve all variables that you need for filtering and than in view just add $filter at the end where you need it.

$data['filter'] can be collected/generated in constructor and defined by default.

It's little bit tricky solution i would rather use session to keep data of that kind and having "reset" button on page.

Comment: Thanks for Suggestions.
Right now, i am working with session indeed.
But Project demand need to use that filters in method GET for our client queries to retrieve data based on that filter.
and Next thing is i can use $data['filter'] in Constructor but cant change all links in project for this.
My thinking either to override the URI class or play with htaccess should have some solutions,

Comment: well gotcha alternative solution via jquery